# Como funciona o XOR para dois binários com mais de um dígito?

Tags: operadores, lógica, operador-lógico, álgebra-booleana

Eu aprendi que o operador XOR funciona como **OU Exclusivo**, ou seja, o resultado final só é **1** quando **apenas um dos operadores** for igual a **1**.

A tabela verdade ilustra bem isto:

[image: Tabela verdade do operador XOR, usando 1 bit]

A minha dúvida é: como funciona o operador XOR com números que não sejam de apenas 1 bit?

Exemplo: `110 XOR 011` deveria retornar qual resultado?

Em JavaScript (ou qualquer outra linguagem) consigo ver que o resultado deve ser **`101`**, mas como chegar neste resultado?

```js
var a = 6; // 110
var b = 3; // 011
var res = (a ^ b).toString(2);

log('a:', a.toString(2));
log('b:', b.toString(2));
log('res.:', res);

// Apenas pra melhor visualização
function log(label, valor) {
    var lb = padLeft(' ', 5, label);
    var val = padLeft('0', 3, valor, true);

    console.log(lb, val);
}

function padLeft(padChar, padSize, str, left) {
    const pad = padChar.repeat(padSize);
    if(left)
        return (pad + str).slice(-padSize);
    else
        return (str + pad).substring(0, padSize);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O sistema de numeração binário não funciona diferente do sistema decimal. Assim como a soma ou multiplicação funciona igual, os operadores lógicos também. Portanto o XOR é feito bit a bit, como você somaria um decimal que é feito algarismo por algarismo, com a vantagem que não tem "vai um" nos operadores lógicos, nem faria sentido porque nessa operação os dígitos não possuem relação de grandeza, como na aritmética que um resultado em uma grandeza pode afetar o resultado da outra. Então:

```
110  => 1  1  0 (pra visualizar melhor)
011  => 0  1  1
---     -------
101  => 1  0  1
```

Só o do meio deu 0 porque ele não é exclusivo. Teria dado 0 se fosse 0 e 0, como no `OR` normal.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

O `XOR` é um `mod 2`, portanto se fossem:

```
110
011
```

Seria igual:

```
(1 + 0) mod 2, (1 + 1) mod 2, (1 + 0) mod 2
```

Assumindo que `,` fosse concatenação, veja isso no [WolfgramAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1+%2B+0)+mod+2,+(1+%2B+1)+mod+2,+(1+%2B+0)+mod+2).

---

Quando se faz isto com duas letras, por exemplo, literalmente `H` e `u`, por exemplo:

```
<?php

echo 'H' ^ 'u';
// Resultado: "="
```

[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6155cb08322193f9c9c61b179ad889aec93e736f)

Na verdade isso ocorre porque seus valores binários são utilizados, [pode também achar a tabela aqui](http://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.htm).

```
01001000 // str_pad(decbin(unpack('C', 'H')[1]), 8, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
01110101 // str_pad(decbin(unpack('C', 'u')[1]), 8, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Aplicando a [mesma formula acima](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(0%2B0)%20mod%202,%20(1%2B1)%20mod%202,%20(0%2B1)%20mod%202,%20(0%2B1)%20mod%202,%20(1%20%2B%200)%20mod%202,%20(0%2B1)%20mod%202,%20(0%2B0)%20mod%202,%20(0%2B1)%20mod%202) teríamos:

```
00111101
```

Que possui em ASCII (assim com em UTF-8) o valor de `=`, *lembrando que nem todo o ASCII pode sem "representado"*.

Portanto se fizemos:

```
echo pack('C', bindec('00111101'));
// Resultado: "="
```

É isto que é feito por trás dos panos, praticamente.

---

*Tentarei refazer este exemplo em Javascript para ficar mais fácil de visualizar.*