# Lógica dessas operações bit a bit

Tags: c, c++, lógica, bitwise

Já tem um bom tempo que quero me iniciar no mundo dos emuladores, resolvi parar de tentar fazer um emulador de um sistema complexo e começar com um bem básico, um emulador de CHIP-8, que é o que muitos indicam em fóruns de emulação. Bem vamos por partes:

Primeira operação que não vejo a logica:

```
std::uint16_t opcode = m_Memory[reg.PC] << 8 | m_Memory[reg.PC + 1];
```

Basicamente 1 opcode do CHIP-8 vale 2 bytes, mas a rom é de 8 bits, primeiro eu acesso o array de std::uint8_t que chamo de m_Memory que usei para armazenar a ROM e o conjunto de fontes na posição do Program Counter que é iniciado como 0x200 que é onde a maioria dos programas/jogos de CHIP-8 começam, depois se adiciona mais 8 zeros, o que é fácil de se compreender, 1 byte = 8 bits, logo 2 bytes são 16 bits, mas ai que começa a confusão, se já obteve o opcode então por que mascarar um valor de 16 bits com 8? e por que usar a própria rom porém avançando a posição do pc?

Aqui vamos para a segunda parte do meu problema:

```
switch (opcode & 0xF000) {
   ...
}
```

Em uma discussão que iniciei em um fórum do reddit sobre emuladores as pessoas me disseram que mascaram o opcode com 0xF000 para obter o opcode real, mas o que não entendi é como chegaram a conclusão que deveriam mascarar e por que com esse valor.

A parte final:

Utilizo [essa documentação](http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/chip8/C8TECH10.HTM#3.0) em que eu e muitos outros se guiam, primeiro vamos ao opcode 0x6000 ou 6xkk ou LD V x , byte:

```
//LD Vx, byte
case 0x6000:
    reg.Vx[(opcode & 0x0F00) >> 8] = (opcode & 0x00FF);
    reg.PC += 2;
    std::cout << "OPCODE LD Vx, byte executado." << std::endl;
    break;
```

O CHIP-8 possui 16 registradores de 8 bits que chamei de Vx, vamos la:

reg.Vx[(opcode & 0x0F00) >> 8]

Primeiro converti o opcode 0x6000 em binário e efetuei a operação and:

```
0110 0000 0000 0000    //0x6000
0000 1111 0000 0000    //0x0F00
-------------------
0000 0000 0000 0000    //0x0
```

Depois `>> 8` move 8 bits a direita o que ficaria `0000 0000` ou seja, o índice 0 de Vx, depois `= (opcode & 0x00FF)` que fica:

```
0110 0000 0000 0000    //0x6000
0000 0000 1111 1111    //0x00FF
-------------------
0000 0000 0000 0000    //0x0
```

Então por que não fazer simplesmente `reg.Vx[0] = 0;` ?

Lembrando que eu nunca tive que fazer operações Bit a Bit antes em nenhum projeto, apenas sei o que os livros me disseram sobre a operação AND, OR, XOR, NOT etc...

Eu gostaria de poder entender essa lógica que as pessoas utilizam para poder utilizar em projetos futuros.

Comment: Algumas coisas relacionadas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175345/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/201392/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178733/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205163/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213615/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/268467/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9497/101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algumas das coisas que você não está entendendo parecem ser porque você não interpretou que há valores que são uma "família" de opcodes, ou parâmetros para um mesmo opcode - todos codificados no valor de 16 bits - e não apenas um valor fixo. O último exemplo, do opcode 0x6000, por exemplo, você fez toda a simulação como se o valor *sempre* fosse ser exatamente 0x6000 - no entanto, veja a documentação:

> 6xkk - LD Vx, byte Set Vx = kk.
>
> The interpreter puts the value kk into register Vx.

Ou seja, o primero "nibble" (primeiros 4 bits) do opcode contém o dígito hexa "6". Os 3 dígitos hexadecimais restantes são os argumentos do opcode.  Então, sim, "0x6000" sempre vai ser "setar V0 = 0x00", mas o opcode 0x62FF quer dizer "setar V2 = 0xFF".  O papel do seu interpretador/emulador é justamente *detectar* que o opcode 6 quer dizer colocar um valor num registrador, extrair esses valores, e executar a operação.

Veja como isso já responde a sua segunda questão-  ao fazer o switch-case com o opcode mascarado com 0xF000, apenas o valor "0x6000"  fica para _comparação como case, mas dentro do código do case, você precisa do opcode na íntegra - é nos outros dígitos do opcode que estão os parâmetros.

```
opcode = 0x62ff;
switch (opcode  & 0xf000):
   ...
   case 0x6000:
       register_number = (opcode & 0x0f00) >> 8;
       value = opcode & 0xff;
       registers[register_number] = value;
       break;
   ...
```

Observe na documentação que nem todos os opcodes são determinados integralmente pelo primeiro dígito hexadecimal - para alguns deles, 
por exemplo, o próprio "0x0", há toda uma sub-família de opcodes -  nesses casos você vai fazer um outro switch/case dentro do primeiro (ou, chamar uma função em C para isso), para testar os outros valores.

E por fim, quanto a:

```
opcode = m_Memory[reg.PC] << 8 | m_Memory[reg.PC + 1];
```

É legível de forma tão clara quanto em português - 
O vetor m_Memory (*) contém valores de 8 bits. Você precisa ler dois bytes  e compor um único valor de 16 bits (e, veja a documentação: o byte mais significativo vem primeiro - ou seja, "big endian" )

> All instructions are 2 bytes long and are stored most-significant-byte
>   first.

Então - você pega o primeiro byte, multiplica ele por 2 ^ 8 usando o shift 8 `<< 8`- ou seja, insere 8 zeros a direita desse byte - e em seguida seta esses 8 dígitos binários inferiores com o valor do próximo byte na memória, usando o `or` binário (como todos os valores correspondentes são 0, o valor do segundo byte é colocado na integra nos bits inferiores do opcode). Em outras palavras: você lê um byte, coloca ele na posição dos bits 15 até 8 do seu opcode, e lê o byte na posição seguinte da memória, na posição dos bits 7 até 0.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(*) Nota separada: você realmente ganha muito pouco ao complicar nomes de variáveis - mesmo que essa seja a prática de estilo em outros exemplos que você esteja lendo: "m_Memory" em vez de "memory" apenas significa 4 toques a mais no teclado, e três sinais de "lixo visual" que seu cérebro tem que descartar ao ler a variável. Não tem muito risco de você ter outra variável "memory"  nesse código, tem?

Comment: Como eu disse eu não tenho muita experiência com bitwise, e eu nunca tinha ouvida falar em endianess até algumas semanas atrás. Mas muito obrigado, por que na operação or o program counter é sempre somado com 1? estudando alguns repositórios sempre noto que ao final de cada instrução faz um acréscimo com 2 ou quando é para pular uma instrução +4.

Comment: Nesse caso a soma é sempre "1" justamente para pegar o próximo byte, que compõe a mesma instrução de 2 bytes. Em "PC + 2" ja está a próxima instrução.

Comment: Muito obrigado, agora pude finalmente achar esta lógica.